# Convert pseudo code in to a schedulable apex class to execute daily

Tags: trigger, scheduled-apex

Convert this pseudo code into an apex schedulable class. Exam name is a autonumber, which increments every time a new exam record is created, but is saved as a String value, not int. so inside this exam with this particular examname, to check the expiration date of it, then set it to expired if it has passed the todays date. if expiration date >= today(), etc.

```
for(x = 1, x<10000, x++){

    convert x to string
    in Exam Object
    where(examname == x){
        get.examstate;
        get.expirationdate;
        }
    if(exam state == ‘Active’){
        if(expirationdate >= today()){  
            set.certification.examstate == ‘expired’;
            sendemailnotification;
        if(exampirationdate >= today()-7){
            sendemailnotification;
        }
        else
            continue;
        }
    continue;
    }
}
```

edited the question, due to a couple of mistakes.

Comment: So you want the exams to expire when they are still set to a future expiration date? I"m not sure that's what you really mean.

Comment: this trigger runs every night. So on a particular date the expiration date will be equal to today's day, I then want it to expire. And also send an email alert(call a workflow?) 7 days before expiration.

Comment: Triggers run in "real-time", not on a schedule. You probably want to use Process Builder or Workflow Rules instead, with a Time-Based/Scheduled action to perform the desired tasks.

Comment: i did a lot of research, and was advised to use scedulable apex. The process builder can not perform such tasks, i have tried plenty of times.
I want the trigger to run everyday at midnight, using a process builder it is hard to implement such a somewhat complex task, i presume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've posted is pseudocode, and the algorithm it is describing is going to work very poorly on the Salesforce platform. One of the hallmarks of Salesforce is that while Apex looks much like Java or another C-family language, the algorithmic approaches you must take are dictated much more by the platform than by the language syntax, and are likely to look very alien to you. Trailhead has some good modules (under the Apex tag) to help you get comfortable with these ideas.

As a first step, I'm suggesting some revisions to your pseudocode algorithm that could be built into a Scheduled Apex class.

```
// Perform one selective query to find the records we need *today*
List<ExamObject__c> objects = [
    SELECT Name, Status__c, Expiration_Date__c 
    FROM ExamObject__c
    WHERE Status__c = 'Active' AND (Expiration_Date__c <= TODAY  
          OR (Expiration_Date__c > TODAY AND Expiration_Date__c < :Date.today() + 7))];

// Iterate over the records and accumulate collections of actions to be taken
for (ExamObject__c thisExam : objects) {
    if(thisExam.Expiration_Date__c < Date.today()){  
        thisExam.Status__c = 'Expired';
        listOfEmailNotifications.add(thisExam);
        listOfUpdates.add(thisExam);
    } else if (thisExam.Expiration_Date__c < Date.today() + 7) {
        listOfEmailNotifications.add(thisExam);
    }
}

// Perform all actions in a single step each.
sendEmailNotifications(listOfEmailNotifications);
update listOfUpdates;
```

In Apex, you never want to be iterating over objects you don't have to (it costs CPU time against the limit). That's one reason why you'll nearly always run a single query at the beginning of your process to query as tightly as possible against the records you need. Then, you'll use collection classes like sets, lists, and maps to accumulate updates and actions you need to perform as you iterate over those records. Finally, you'll perform each of those actions in a single bulk command.

For your next steps, you'll probably want to work through these Trailhead modules:

- [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_database)
- [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_bulk), which talks about bulk patterns.
- [Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex)

Comment: This look great David, now I understand how this works. So this is like basically accessing data from a database and updating it, sorta I guess. I will look in to this code you have provided, make the necessary alterations and try it out. Thank you for the links you have provided, I will get back to you If I have any doubts. Thanks alot!

Comment: @NivethKumar, it's not a big deal, but is there a reason you've elected to unaccept this answer?

Comment: sorry I might have clicked it by mistake. thanks for the help. I was able to figure out the code. How do I get the email to be sent? can you provide me with some links?

Comment: I would start with the documentation for [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#!).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write a scheduled apex, working code if anyone needs it.

```
/*creates a schedulable class, which means you can call this in scheduled jobs to run at a certain time (eg. once a day, once a week etc.)*/
global class newClass implements Schedulable {

    /*the code given within this method will be executed*/
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    /*List any salesforce object, change the value within <>*/
        List<Exam__c> objects = [
       /*Select the fields within the object you want to use*/
            SELECT Name, Exam_state__c, Expiration__c 
            FROM Exam__c
       /*Specify field values to have a more specific search*/
            WHERE Exam_state__c = 'Active' AND Expiration__c <= TODAY];
        /*loop through these selected specific objects*/
        for(Exam__c c : objects){
            if(c.Expiration__c <= Date.today()){  
        /*set new value for a specific field if it matches the criteria*/
                c.Exam_state__c = 'Expired';
            } 
        }
    /*apply the previously set value, this is an important step which actually makes the changes and updates the database*/
        update objects;
    }
}
```